# UITextView in IB but not in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITextView in my IB:
[image]

However when I run the simulator and go into this view, it's not there:
[image]

How is this even possible??

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this have background.

Comment: Check the frame of the table view and the textfield. I think that causes the issue

Comment: I figured out the issue is in the orientation, how can I create a view that works for both potrait and landscape and would adjust the sizes dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the height of your tableview , as as per my concern you had anvigtion bar at the top which cause the issue.

Comment: turns out the issue is the orientation... when I switch the orientation to potrait I can see it, however under landscape it's hidden down below... how do I solve this then?

Comment: then you had to adjust the frame size of your tableview and textview, when you are changing orientation,You can do it in interface builder

Comment: how do people handle this issue with orientation layout? I am a bit confused

Comment: Check this link ,http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad    here is tutorial which tells how to do auto resizing in interface builder.Hope it helps you .....

Answer (score 0):

i think your tableview is overlap on your textview... 
check your textview with back ground color else check other view with back ground color property...with this u can identify which view hide your textview

Comment: I checked that as well and it doesn't seem to be the case... I've made my textview to have a background color so I can identify this

Comment: @aherlambang: Have you tried moving the textfield and label up a bit? It might be the whole view is pushed down a little (outside of your simulator's screen) because of your view being in a view, or something like that. Long story short, try to move your textfield up to, say, the middle. That way you can make sure it's not the location that is the error, but the textfield itself.

Comment: i think you check your all view's hide property one by one.. also check with hidden your table if you see your textview then decrease your tableview height